# How to get SVG animations to work cross-browser within <use> tag

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to create animated svgs to use them in a web. I created some but had problems to visualize them in my mobile phone. I could see some of the animations, but not all.

The issue appears (as far as I've tested) in Safari (desktop version) and all the navigators on my mobile phone (running iOS 12.1.1). I don't know it's behavior in other OS mobile phones.

After searching for a similar issue I couldn't find the origin of the problem nor a solution. Initially it seemed to be related to the -webkit- prefix, but some animations and transforms worked while others didn't. Finally I started doing my own tests and I think I've found the origin. It seems to be related to the `<use>` tag.

When trying to animate an within a `<use>` tag safari doesn't animate it.

An SVG to illustrate it would be:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <path id="shortSegment" d="M0 5a5 5 0 0 1 0 -10h20a5 5 0 0 1 0 10Z"/>
    <path id="longSegment" d="M0 5a5 5 0 0 1 0 -10h40a5 5 0 0 1 0 10Z"/>
    <g id="arrow">
      <use xlink:href="#shortSegment"  transform="rotate(135)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#shortSegment" transform="rotate(225)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#longSegment" transform="rotate(180)"/>
    </g>
    ...
  </defs>
  ...
  <use id="mainArrow" xlink:href="#arrow" x="275" y="300""/>
</svg>
```

With the following CSS:

```css
@keyframes ShakingTail {
  0% {transform: rotate(-5deg)}
  50% {transform: rotate(5deg)}
  100% {transform: rotate(-5deg)}
}
#longSegment { animation: ShakingTail 0.5s linear infinite; }
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/alebrant/pen/MWgrVVZ) with that code and some more.

In the example provided, the moving animation works fine in safari and iOS navigators, but the shaking tail in the arrows don't.

The only way I can think of to solve the problem is taking the animated elements out of the `<use>` tag, but:

- I'd like to keep the reusability and readability that <use> provides.

  That solution isn't always viable (in the provided example, there are a lot of tail of the arrows, they are within another animation, each could have its own transforms applied, etc).

  Animating outside the element makes it much more difficult to apply certain transforms like scale and rotate (because it transforms over 0 0 and transform-origin doesn't apply), almost making complex matrix functions a must.

Is there a fancier way of working around that issue? I'd rather avoid SMIL, because I plan to trigger the animation with :hover and with an SMIL animation that would require JS too.

Comment: I'd like to avoid SMIL. Mainly because later I'd like to trigger the animation by :hover and SMIL would require JS. And the deprecation attempt from chrome doesn't makes SMIL attractive at all. I update the question adding this information. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm. I thought it did. I'll try that, even though I'd prefer a CSS solution.

Comment: I said that I prefer a CSS solution, not that I can't have one. I just tried the SMIL approach and it works on Safari, making use of the mouseover thanks to the link you provided. The animation works fine in both Chrome and Safari when triggering from a mouse event in the svg. But in chrome it doesn't (iOS navigators neither). I created this new [codepen](https://codepen.io/alebrant/pen/dybJKoq) to illustrate it.